# Why are there disputes about the content of this post which is relevant to Google?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts

Link to the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23005799

Here is the revision that introduced the disputed content: https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/23005799/7

Why was the edit removed, and the post locked for disputed content?

Regarding the edit, the U.S. government has already started the investigation:

- [State Attorneys General announce Google antitrust probe *(**Sep 9, 2019**, video, speech of the Generals)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svKxpQ8amiY)
- [50 Attorneys General open antitrust probe into Google *(**Sep 9, 2019**, short video, news)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qEPpEwtKfaI)

*(And, my edit to the answer above was made in **Jul 20, 2019**, over 50 days ago, and it's marked as `disputed` just now, 2 or 3 days after the investigation announced, is that just a coincidence ? I don't think so.)*

---

### @Update - more links

***(which help to prove the facts in the contents get deleted)***

- [Gen. Robert Spalding: Breaking Google Up Is not Enough *(**Sep 20, 2019**, video, interview)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IlF4VC3Zgq4&t=1041)
  *(Start from **17:21**, in case you are short of time.)*
- [Vice President Mike Pence's China Speech at Hudson Institute *(**Oct 04, 2019**, video, speech)*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mYAHPPXmcts&t=2265)
  *(Start from **37:45**, in case you are short of time.)*

Comment: I mean. that edit is quite obviously political in nature and rightfully rolled back.

Comment: @KevinB It's all truth, nothing else.

Comment: it is *your* truth, in addition to facts. not just facts.

Comment: @KevinB Which part is not fact ?

Comment: I will not quote them here.

Comment: @EricWang *"It's all truth"* - Who cares if it is or isn't? it's irrelevant to the post

Comment: @NickA It's the reason of why part of the answer doesn't work any more, so it's relevant to the answer. You may not care, someone else do.

Comment: @EricWang No, the only *remotely* relevant part is *"I'm sorry, but Google itself has killed the solution of GAE & XX-NET, due to changing of GAE ip police (one of the main reason is the ip pool reduced from millions to hundreds)."*, the rest is just a waste of keypresses

Comment: Hey guys.  This question shouldn't be closed.  Closing it is a silly decision.

Comment: "stories", yes, "stories"

Comment: @KevinB Which part is story, provide fact not fancy words.

Comment: Quick question for you. If someone edited a pro-Bernie Sanders rant into their answer, or a rant in favour of the Hong Kong protests, and someone else edited it out, would you object to the removal in the same manner as you're doing here?

Comment: @F1Krazy That's not an exact proper metaphor in this case I think, as I explained above, I think my additional content has higher chance to be considered as the reason of the expiry of my original answer. Anyhow, to your question: I am 100% supporter for `Hong Kong protests`, and if someone added it, I see it, I will up vote it, even in that case it may be considered irrelevant by many others.

Comment: You might have better luck on dev.to

Comment: And I'm not doing advertisement, I only edited one post with the reason I myself considered relevant, and that's triggered by the original answer invalided (and part of the reason it became invalid was due to some of Google's action).

Comment: You're probably not wrong, someone likely flagged it after doing a search that your answer came up in. that doesn't make the moderator's action suspect or invalid, it just means your change went unnoticed till now. **it's Very likely that the new answer posted today prompted it.**

Comment: @KevinB Maybe that's the case.

Comment: This is a legitimate question to bring to Meta; especially since the reason for locking says to bring it to meta.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**Your first sentence seems to be materially relevant, and should likely be kept.**  This gets at the heart of a specific implementation and would be useful to add in as a warning to others should they wish to go down this road.

> Google itself has killed the solution of GAE & XX-NET, due to changing of GAE ip police.

**Everything *else*** is noise and immaterial to the conversation, irrespective of its "truth".  You add more noise to the signal of, "Oh, why can't I do X with GAE now?" by adding that information.  We don't expect engineers to be experts on the political landscape, so adding that information would only further confound and confuse someone.

Comment: This answer is pretty fair in the content of SO, though I still consider the `noise` part to be very import. I might re-post it somewhere else (not SO or SE sites) later, where the topic is more relevant.

Comment: Even if you consider it to be important, the "why" doesn't affect the fact of it being killed off.

Comment: @Eric it's important, sure. Is it 'SO content'? No.

Comment: @EricWang: The only reason why I think it's noise is that government policy change and its justifications have been subject to change.  If you want some bedtime reading on that very thing, [you can look at the whole Huawei mess](https://www.androidauthority.com/huawei-google-android-ban-988382/).  An engineer trying to do A Thing™ with GAE isn't going to have time to parse all of that.

Comment: @Makoto Thanks, actually I had try to persuade people not to buy huawei's cellphones even several years ago, only recently the US start to wake up and take actions. There are many "interesting" topics on Youtube especially in last 2 years, huawei is just one of them.

Comment: @EricWang: You're missing my point but also demonstrating my point, somehow, some way...

Comment: @Makoto Indeed I read it several times, but not sure what it means ... and my last comment is just try to express my standpoint, and that I'm quite interested in & aware of the rapid changing of the world recently.

Comment: The "rapidly changing world" isn't relevant on SO unless it pertains to programming.

Comment: I have added more links in the question, if anyone is still interested, which help to prove the facts I had provided in the deleted content.

Comment: @EricWang:  **You're missing the point.**  You don't need to keep adding facts to back up the noise.  **It's *noise***.  An engineer skimming Stack Overflow does not ***care*** about the shifting or evolving political landscape in software development.  **Please don't add it in.**  It's not going to change the fact that it's still noise.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not missing the point, I get those points. And as long as adding links don't violate the rules of SO's meta site, I will add it if I have time & think it's proper.

Comment: @ericwang adding context is important. Software and programming doesn’t exist in a vacuum free from politics. However the tenor of what you added to your answer on SO was inappropriate and inflammatory. If you could state objective reasons for the changes, that’s ok. It’s the subjective commentary that has no place here.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker I'm not arguing about or trying to revert the deleted content any more. I know SO is just about programming. I'm just adding links that are relevant to the above question itself, that's a valid operation, right?